# How can i achieve that a change in one object does not change the other with python

Tags: python, class

I try to instanciate two objects of a house with a bedroom and a living room.
If i change the pieces of furniture in one house the other one should not change.

```
class room:
    def __init__(self,name,piecesoffurniture):
        self.name=name
        self.piecesoffurniture=piecesoffurniture
class house:
    def __init__(self,rooms):
        self.rooms=rooms

bedroom=room("bedroom",2)
livingroom=room("livingroom",3)
rooms=[]
rooms.append(bedroom)
rooms.append(livingroom)
myhouse=house(rooms)
yourhouse=house(rooms)
myhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture=4
print(bedroom.piecesoffurniture)
print(yourhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture)
```

output:

4

4

This is a sample code for my program where the constructor of room is very slow and the constructor of house is very fast.

Comment: You are using the same list in both cases. Copy the list before instancing the class.

Comment: aside, python class names should be Capitalised

Comment: Probably a good general read on (im)mutable objects: https://www.afternerd.com/blog/difference-between-list-tuple/ Especially point 2. Debugging

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Room`, `class House` - it helps to recognize class in code. And many IDEs use special colors for these names to make it more readable - even Stackoverflow uses other color for `CamelCaseNames`. You could also use spaces around `=` to make it more readable - see more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: So i copied my list but the output stayed the same:                      

bedroom=room("bedroom",2)                        

livingroom=room("livingroom",3)  

rooms=[]

rooms.append(bedroom)

rooms.append(livingroom)

room1=rooms

room2=rooms

myhouse=house(room1)

yourhouse=house(room2)

myhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture=4

print(bedroom.piecesoffurniture)

print(yourhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture)

output:

4
4

Comment: If i change my list to a tuple the output also stays the same:

bedroom=room("bedroom",2)
livingroom=room("livingroom",3)
rooms=(bedroom,livingroom)

room1=rooms
room2=rooms
myhouse=house(room1)
yourhouse=house(room2)
myhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture=4
print(bedroom.piecesoffurniture)
print(yourhouse.rooms[0].piecesoffurniture)

output: 4
4

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent

This link solved my problem

I had to use copy.deepcopy(list)